# How to generate a RGB565 Bitmap with Bitmap.setPixel()?

Tags: android, bitmap, rgb, argb

the Bitmap.setPixels() doesn't seem to help~ It only fills the bitmap with ARGB value.

```
 img=Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,Config.RGB_565);
 img.setPixels(Y, 0, mWidth, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
```

No matter how I fill `int[]Y` ,it seems to provide the Bitmap with `ARGB_8888` value
(e.g .`Y[i]=0xffffff00`  presents yellow int `ARGB_8888`  ,but when i set the config to be `RGB_565` ,it presents yellow too... Is there any explanation for this? )

Answer (score 0):

The input array specified as the first parameter to `setPixels()` is an array of `ARGB_8888` int values no matter what the format of the Bitmap. From the [setPixels() documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixels(int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)):

> Replace pixels in the bitmap with the colors in the array. Each element in the array is a packed **int** prepresenting a non-premultiplied **ARGB Color**.

If the Bitmap format is `RGB_565` then `setPixels()` will perform the conversion from `ARGB_8888` to `RGB_565`.

If you want to supply `RGB_565` data (assuming the format of the Bitmap if `RGB_565`) then use [copyPixelsFromBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsFromBuffer(java.nio.Buffer)):

> Copy the pixels from the buffer, beginning at the current position, overwriting the bitmap's pixels. The data in the buffer is not changed in any way (unlike setPixels(), which converts from unpremultipled 32bit to whatever the bitmap's native format is.

You can define the pixels as an array of shorts and wrap it using [ShortBuffer.wrap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ShortBuffer.html#wrap(short[])) and pass that to `copyPixelsFromBuffer`. It accepts any `Buffer` object however.

Comment: thanks for your advice!        If the Bitmap format is RGB_565 then setPixels() will perform the conversion from ARGB_8888 to RGB_565.   this doesn't seem to work . I use canvas.drawBitmap to see the result ,the color is strange.